# How to set Selection.Start in VBA?

Tags: vba, selection

I have a problem with adjusting selection inside of a table. I have a function that goes through a document word by word to analyze it's contents looking for specific patterns. Unfortunately, in tables `Char(7)` character breaks the selection - when  it's selected, all cells become selected automatically. To work around this problem I store the proper `Selection.Start` parameter.

Here is my code:

```
If InStr(Selection.text, Char(7)) > 0 Then
    Selection.start = selStart
    Selection.End = selStart + (Len(tekst) - 2)
End If
```

Well, it did not help. I can see, while debugging, that `selStart` is 441 and `Selection.Range.Start` is 427 (427 would be the beginning of the cell, when the word I'm looking for is on the position of 441). In the next step... `Selection.Start` still is 427.

I've also tried another aproach using `MoveStart` and `MoveEnd` but no matter what I do, the `Selection.Start` doesn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well of course!
I can't move Selection.Start, while Chr(7) is in the selection! Everything works perfectly when I move Selection.End fisrt...

```
If InStr(Selection.text, Chr(7)) > 0 Then
    Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
    Selection.start = selStart
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a different approach is in order: rather than manipulate the selection, iterate the `Document.Words` collection.  Something like:

```
Sub PreccessAllWords()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim wd As Range

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    For Each wd In doc.Words
        If wd.Text = "Foo " Then
            wd.Text = "Bar "
        End If
    Next wd
End Sub
```

Comment: It's a bigger system with only this small error to correct, changing whole approach is a bit too much. Selection is being changed not only to iterate threw text, but also as a result of a macro proper text MUST be selected.